# How to dynamically populate Jenkins Choice Parameter with GitLab images from a specific repository

Tags: git, image, jenkins, parameters, gitlab

I have a Jenkins job where I need to create a dropdown list that dynamically fetches and displays GitLab images from a specified repository in the GitLab Container Registry. I want to enable users to select an image from this dropdown as a parameter for further actions or deployments within the job.
I would greatly appreciate any assistance or a concrete example demonstrating how to achieve this functionality.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to do this.

**Using Docker to get the Image List.**

The following example uses Amazon ECR, you can do similar with the Gitlab registry as well. Instead of `aws ecr list` you can simply do `docker images....` after login into the container registry.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                echo 'Hello World'
                script {
                    REPOSITORY_NAME = 'ycr-repository'
                    REGION = 'us-east-1'
                    INPUT_IMAGE_TO_DELETE = input message: 'Please Select Docker Image to delete', ok: 'Next',
                                                          parameters: [
                                                          choice(name: 'IMAGE_NAME', choices: getDockerImages(REPOSITORY_NAME), description: 'Select Docker Image to delete')]
                                                    
                    
                    echo "Deleting the image: ${INPUT_IMAGE_TO_DELETE}" 
                    sh "aws ecr batch-delete-image --repository-name $REPOSITORY_NAME --image-ids imageTag=$INPUT_IMAGE_TO_DELETE --region $REGION"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

def getDockerImages(REPOSITORY_NAME) {
    output = sh(returnStdout: true, script: "aws ecr list-images --repository-name $REPOSITORY_NAME --output json").trim()
    json = readJSON text: output
    println json
    return json.imageIds.imageTag
}
```

**Update**

If the image tags are not present in the local registry you can all the [registry RestAPI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/container_registry.html#within-a-project-1) to get the images.

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/5/registry/repositories/2/tags"
```

Comment: I cannot use 'docker images ls' to list all the images in my GitLab registry. The 'docker images ls' command only lists the images that have been pulled into your local Docker environment.

Comment: @AssiaKhateeb Check the update in the answer.